# Using python generate random names and address to csv format

Tags: python

Using python how do i generate randon names in the format of random email, first name , last name, address, city, state, zip, country(USA only)

Comment: You make a list of each of those things, and then use random.choice on it each one

Comment: In addition to @MikeTung you can also find a database(s) and fetch the lists.

Comment: I'm sure if OP tries he can do it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate random names you will need to have a database of names. However, if you can pass off any combination of letters as names then you can achieve this using random.choice. Refer below code which prints out 15 names and the length of names is between 3 and 25 characters. You can extend the same logic for random emails.

```
import random
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
random.choice(letters)

population = 15

for a in range(population):
    print(" ")
    for b in range(random.randint(3,25)):
        print(random.choice(letters), end='')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick turn up. I have found a link that gives me list of all random names. It’s https://www.mockaroo.com. Can we pull data from this ?